# Material UI components not returning an HTMLElement reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

For a couple of libraries on element observing, I require the ref prop to return an HTMLElement, however, 99% of MUI components don't do that. What am I missing? How can I get a reference to the root element of a component?

For a couple of libraries on element observing, I require the ref prop to return an HTMLElement, however, 99% of MUI components don't do that. What am I missing? How can I get a reference to the root element of a component?

```
import React, {
    useState, useRef
} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import useInView from "react-hook-inview";
import {
    Card
}
from "@material-ui/core";

function App() {
    const container = useRef();
    const[inViewport, setInViewport] = useState(false);
    useInView({
        target: container,
        unobserveOnEnter: true,
        onEnter: () = > setInViewport(true)
    });
    console.log(container);
    return ( < Card ref = {
            container
        }
        style = {
            {
                textAlign: "center"
            }
        } >
        <h1>{inViewport ? "In viewport" : "Not in viewport"}</h1> < /Card>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App / > , rootElement);
```

[Live Demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0o425kj290). You can see the logged ref is to withStyles instead of an HTMLElement reference.

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Comment: @HRK44 I have updated the initial question with a full example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the RootRef component for this purpose: https://material-ui.com/api/root-ref/#rootref-api

Since most of the Material-UI components in v3 are implemented as classes, a `ref` in those cases will point at the class instance (this is just the React behavior for class-based components). Material-UI provides the RootRef component as a way to get at the underlying DOM element.

For v4 of Material-UI, many (perhaps most/all by the time a stable version is released) of the components are being converted to function components and the `ref` behavior will then be different and many/most of them should then forward refs such that they provide access to the DOM element.